# Implement ICustomProperty in C++/WinRT

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I am trying to do [data `{Binding}` via `ICustomProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property#using-the-binding-markup-extension-with-cwinrt) (there's no example available in Microsoft documentation) in C++/WinRT as follow:

```
#include "winrt\Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;

struct MyCustomProperty : winrt::implements<MyCustomProperty, ICustomProperty>
{
// To be implemented
};

static MyCustomProperty TitleProperty;

struct MyCustomObject : winrt::implements<MyCustomObject, ICustomPropertyProvider>
{
    ICustomProperty GetCustomProperty(winrt::hstring name)
    {
        return TitleProperty.try_as<ICustomProperty>();
    }
    // Other methods omitted
};
```

Unfortunately, there's compilation error:

**Error C2039: 'try_as': is not a member of 'MyCustomProperty'**

Note that simply `return TitleProperty;` doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After digesting the cryptic jargons in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-apis#instantiating-and-returning-implementation-types-and-interfaces), the solution is to create my static property instance using `winrt::make` function template:

```
static ICustomProperty TitleProperty = winrt::make<MyCustomProperty>();
```

And then I can simply return it later:

```
ICustomProperty GetCustomProperty(winrt::hstring name)
{
    return TitleProperty;
}
```

The documentation of `winrt::make` merges both cases (runtime class vs. non-runtime class) into one without concrete examples for my non-runtime use case.